# how to use increments in equation

Tags: python

```
def number():
    b = 0.1
    while True:
        yield round(b,1)
        b = b + 0.1
       
b = number()
for i in range(10):
    print(next(b))
```

---

Outputs

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
```

---

Let's get something straight.
I want to use the above ten output numbers below the equation. Could you again tell me, please?

```
z=math.sqrt(b/(1-b))
x=math.sqrt((b+a)/(1-b))
c=math.sqrt(1-b)
V=(m*3.14+math.atan(z)+math.atan(x))/(2*c)
print("V=",V)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'generator'

Comment: You can use `b = list(b)` to convert the iterator to a list, but you can't do math on a list in straight Python, so even `1-b` is invalid.  You need to switch to `numpy`, where that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you set `b` in that for loop?

```
b_gen = number()
for i in range(10):
    b = next(b_gen)
    z=math.sqrt(b/(1-b))
    x=math.sqrt((b+a)/(1-b))
    c=math.sqrt(1-b)
    V=(m*3.14+math.atan(z)+math.atan(x))/(2*c)
    print("V=",V)
```

Comment: Better to use `for b in b_gen:` so you don't assume the length.  Better yet is to use `numpy`, where he doesn't need loops at all.